# How to change dropdown's items according to another dropdown selection when using FutureBuilder?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have two drop downs the second one's items is dynamic according to the first selected item drop down **How to do it ?** I can two two separate drop downs but how to make it depends on the pther one

```
 FutureBuilder(future: getCities(),builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Post> snapshot) {
                      return DropdownButton<String>(
                        hint: new Text(city),
                        items: cities.map((String value) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: new Text(value),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String value) {
                          setState(() => city = value);
                          setState(() => getAreas(2));
                        },
                      );
                    }),
                    FutureBuilder(future: What to write here ?????,builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Post> snapshot) {
                      return DropdownButton<String>(
                        hint: new Text(area),
                        items: areas.map((String value) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: new Text(value),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String value) {
                          setState(() => area = value);
                        },
                      );
                    })
```

Comment: The items for the second drop down would be available immediately or you need to fetch them from somewhere based on the selection in the first drop down?

Comment: my problem is I have a List of string which is null at first and will be filled with strings and is dynamic I want the changes to be reflected on the drop down list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're using the FutureBuilder widget correctly. You shouldn't call the getCities() method directly in your FutureBuilder declaration and you should be using the snapshot reference in the builder. The code below would be in your state class where you use this FutureBuilders:

```
// I see that you have the AsyncSnapshot be of type Post... is there where you get // the cities list or how exactly you initialize cities list?
Future citiesFuture; // the cities future
Future areasFuture; // the data for the second drop down

// get the Future for the cities
@override void initState() {
   super.initState();
   citiesFuture = getCities();
}
```

Then you first FutureBuilder will be :

```
FutureBuilder(future: citiesFuture, builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Post> snapshot) {
      // here you would initialize the cities list
      List cities = snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : [];
                      return DropdownButton<String>(
                        hint: new Text(city),
                        items: cities.map((String value) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: new Text(value),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String value) {
                          setState(() {
                             areasFuture = getAreas(2))
                          });
                        },
                      );
                    }),
```

Your should replace the second FutureBuilder with a method call to this method:

```
Widget provideSecondDropdown() {
    if (areasFuture == null) {
       // the user didn't select anything from the first dropdown so you probably want to show a disabled dropdown
       return DropdownButton<String>(                        
                        items: [],
                        onChanged:null,
    }
    // return the FutureBuilder based on what the user selected
    return FutureBuilder(future: areasFuture, builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Post> snapshot) {
                      List areas = snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : [] 
                      return DropdownButton<String>(
                        hint: new Text(area),
                        items: areas.map((String value) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: new Text(value),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String value) {
                          setState(() => area = value);
                        },
                      );
                    })
}
```